# What's the Easiest Way to Fade a Background Color using jQuery without -UI or Plugins

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and have a Table that I'm using with Edit-in-Place functionality and want to be able to fade off the contextual table classes( `tr.success`, `tr.danger`, etc) and have been searching everywhere to do something like this without adding jQuery-UI to my project since jQ-UI does not play nicely with Boostrap without some extra leg-work.

The only other alternative seems to deal with using the jQuery Colors plugin with `$.animate()` but this alters the CSS and messes with alternating table row colors.

I need to be able to slowly fade-out the contextual table row class without directly modifying the CSS and without using jQUery UI or other plugins as neither are able to exactly meet my specific need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to do this (after spending much of yesterday searching without much luck) is to make use of LESS, and the Bootstrap 3 `.table-row-variant()` mixin.

For this I'm using a solution specific to Bootstrap 3, HOWEVER modifying this to use elsewhere should not be at all difficult.

In the Bootstrap LESS folder, open `mixins.less` and search for `.table-row-variant()` and after this, add the following:

```
// Generate Classes to Fade-off contextual table classes
.table-row-variant-fade(@state; @background) {

  .state-fade(@fade-value; @state; @background) when (@fade-value =< 10) {
    .table > thead > tr,
    .table > tbody > tr,
    .table > tfoot > tr {
      > td.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value},
      > th.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value},
      &.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value} > td,
      &.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value} > th {
        background-color: lighten(@background, unit(@fade-value, '%'));
      }
    }

    // Hover states for `.table-hover`
    // Note: this is not available for cells or rows within `thead` or `tfoot`.
    .table-hover > tbody > tr {
      > td.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value}:hover,
      > th.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value}:hover,
      &.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value}:hover > td,
      &.@{state}-fade-@{fade-value}:hover > th {
        background-color: darken(lighten(@background, unit(@fade-value, '%')), 5%);
      }
    }

    .state-fade((@fade-value + 1); @state; @background;);
  }

  .state-fade(1; @state; @background;);
}
```

This will allow us to generate 10 classes (eg `.CONTEXT-fade-N`) which we can cycle through with jQuery.

Next, we actually need to generate the classes. Save `mixins.less` and open `tables.less` and search for `.table-row-variant()` and after the last variant mixin call, add the following, save and close:

```
.table-row-variant-fade(success; @state-success-bg);
.table-row-variant-fade(info; @state-info-bg);
.table-row-variant-fade(warning; @state-warning-bg);
.table-row-variant-fade(danger; @state-danger-bg);
```

Now we have a bunch of extra table-variant classes which will allow us to fade out the contextual background color. (Note, we don't touch the text color) (also note you can opt to only create fading variants for the contextual classes you will need/want to fade away)

Now we need some jQuery.

Let's assume we have a row, with some cells, and a button with the class `save` which triggers our save of the record.

```
<tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td> <button class="btn btn-primary save">Save Record</button></td>
</tr>
```

In our Save click event handler, when we want to highlight the saved row, and then fade the highlight away, we use setTimeout() and jQuery's even triggering system to accomplish this. Below, we apply the `success` contextual class, add a couple `data-*` attributes to tell the event handler about the fade we're doing, and we set the first fade tick to happen after 1.5 seconds (you can adjust this as you like).

```
$('tbody').on('click', '.save', function(){

    var $this = $(this).button('loading');
    var $target = $($this.data('target'));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {

            $target.data('fade-state', 'success')
                .data('fade-val', 1)
                .addClass('success');

            setTimeout(function(){
                $target.trigger('doFade');
            }, 1500);

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // ...
        }

    }).always(function() {
        $this.button('reset');
    });

});
```

The magic!:
Here, we're simply adding and removing the fading context classes (as well as removing the original context class variant), and updating the `data-fade-val` attribute to keep track of our current fade-step.

```
$('tbody').on('doFade', 'tr', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    var fadeState = $this.data('fade-state');
    var fadeVal = parseInt($this.data('fade-val'));

    $this.removeClass(fadeState + ' ' + fadeState + '-fade-' + (fadeVal - 1)).addClass(fadeState + '-fade-' + fadeVal);

    $this.data('fadeVal', ++fadeVal);

    if(fadeVal <= 10) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.trigger('doFade');
        }, 100);
    } else {
        $this.removeClass(fadeState + '-fade-' + (fadeVal - 1));
    }

});
```

Fading off the class in this way has the benefit of not touching the CSS, and making it super simple to update our theme without having to dive into the JS files for adjustments. And because we're not touching the CSS, we can play nice with BootStrap (specifically in this instance Bootstrap Tables) and we don't have to worry about messing with the bootstrap theme once our animation is done, as we simply remove the final CSS classes, and we're back to normal without any additional cleaning up.

Comment: Thanks @APAD1, if anyone has something better, I'd love to see it, but thus far it seems this is the only way to fade the background that keeps the operation native to Bootstrap.